# Rebase issue when use GIT Bash

Tags: git, rebase

I have a problem when you im using resolve a conflict after push review to Gerrit.
These are my steps:

```
# update from remote
$ git fetch

# get my change from gerrit
$ git fetch ssh://hoang.nth@localhost:29418/Git_training_class2 refs/changes/25/325/1 && git checkout FETCH_HEAD
# git rebase and problem
$ git rebase origin/master
You are not currently on a branch.
Please specify which branch you want to rebase against.
See git-rebase(1) for details.
    git rebase <branch>

D:\SVMC-Testing-Project>git branch
* (HEAD detached at FETCH_HEAD)
  master
D:\SVMC-Testing-Project>git --version
git version 2.9.3.windows.1
```

In only happened in Git bash, but when i used linux environment, it was okay.

So in this case, how can i fixed this problem in window, cauze alot of our developers are using window.

Best Regards,

Comment: I don't know what `git rebase and problem` is supposed to be doing, but it looks like you are in the detached HEAD state, and you are not on a branch.  Rightfully, Git is telling you that it can't do a rebase.  To fix this, just checkout the branch you want to rebase.

Comment: yes,i know that, but when i used on linux, it was fine.

Comment: How about `git rebase origin/master HEAD`? `git rebase origin/master` on detached HEAD is okay with git version 2.10.0.windows.1.

Comment: I tried but it seems same problem:
D:\SVMC-Testing-Project>git rebase origin/master HEAD
You are not currently on a branch.
Please specify which branch you want to rebase against.
See git-rebase(1) for details.

    git rebase <branch>

Answer (score 0):

Git should allow you to rebase any HEAD, even a detached one...

Looks like you may have hit a bug. First, try to update your git version (as the latest is 2.13.1-2).

A workaround would be to use a temporary branch:

```
$ git fetch ssh://hoang.nth@localhost:29418/Git_training_class2 refs/changes/25/325/1
$ git checkout --force -b temp_branch FETCH_HEAD
  # now you are a branch 'temp_branch' so git shouldn't complain anymore
$ git rebase origin/master
  # should work
```

Comment: Dear Mr Zigarn,
i tried to update the version to 2.13, and did as you said, and then git asked me to set the temp_branch as upstream. :(

$git --version
git version 2.13.1.windows.2

$git branch
  master
* temp_branch

$git rebase origin/master
There is no tracking information for the current branch.
Please specify which branch you want to rebase against.
See git-rebase(1) for details.

    git rebase <branch>

If you wish to set tracking information for this branch you can do so with:

    git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/<branch> temp_branch

Comment: Ok. What's the result of 'git branch -avv'? And 'git remote -avv'?

Comment: Looks like, for some reason, you don't have an 'origin/master' branch.

Answer (score 0):

i tried to update the version to 2.13, and did as you said, and then git asked me to set the temp_branch as upstream. :(

```
$git --version
git version 2.13.1.windows.2

$git branch
  master
* temp_branch

$git rebase origin/master
There is no tracking information for the current branch.
Please specify which branch you want to rebase against.
See git-rebase(1) for details.

    git rebase <branch>

If you wish to set tracking information for this branch you can do so with:

    git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/<branch> temp_branch
```